# Getting high training accuracy but wrong predictions for training set

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to get predictions for the training set but I always get the same result for every image. Could someone help me please?

This is how I defined the network:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, image_size_h, image_size_v, num_channels])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def conv_net(x1, weights, biases):
    # First Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d_pool(x1, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'], 'conv1')
    #print(conv1.get_shape())

    # Second Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'], 'conv2')
    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'], 'conv3')
    conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'],'conv4')
    conv5 = conv2d(conv4, weights['wc5'], biases['bc5'],'conv5')
    conv6 = conv2d(conv5, weights['wc6'], biases['bc6'],'conv6')
    # Fully connected layer
    fc1 = fullycon(conv6, weights['wd1'], biases['bd1'], 'fc1')
    # Dropout
    fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob)
    fc2 = fullytanh(fc1_drop, weights['wd2'], biases['bd2'], 'fc2')
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc2, weights['out']), biases['bout'])
    return out
pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases)

prediyo = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(pred), axis=1)
# Loss and optimizer

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_,axis=1), tf.argmax(pred,axis=1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(cost)
```

While I get the prediction by doing:

```
result_boxes_n = normalise_images(result_boxes)

for n in range (0,result_boxes.shape[0]):

    predicted = prediyo.eval(feed_dict={x:np.reshape(result_boxes_n[n,:,:,:],(1,9,8,3)), keep_prob: 1})
    print(predicted)
```

predicted outputs always the same class, although training accuracy is higher than 90%. However, if I do:

```
prediyo.eval(feed_dict={x:result_boxes_n, keep_prob: 1})
```

it works, but no when I try to do individual predictions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your cost function ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it: cross_entropy_cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=predictions)

Comment: It seems everything is ok with your code, give some information about your data, how do you label your images, how many labels do you have, how many images do you have. Maybe the problem is about your dataset.

Comment: I don't think so, because when I predict the whole data set at the same time as I did with: prediyo.eval(feed_dict={x:result_boxes_n, keep_prob: 1}) it gives the expected 90% accuracy